# Hermite interpolation in python with out using scipy library

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, numerical-methods, hermite

```
def hermite_interpolation(x, y, yp, xi):
    n = len(x) - 1
    result = 0.0

    for j in range(n + 1):
        term = y[j]
        for i in range(n + 1):
            if i != j and x[j] != x[i]:
                term *= (xi - x[i]) / (x[j] - x[i])
        result += term * (1 + 2 * (xi - x[j]) / (x[j] - x[i])) * (xi - x[j]) ** 2

    return result
```

error:

> divide by zero encountered in scalar divide
> `result += term * (1 + 2 * (xi - x[j]) / (x[j] - x[i] )) * (xi - x[j])**2`

the function i want to interpolate is `y = 1 / (x**2 + 1)` in the interval of [0,1] for equal spaced point.
i tried to add epsilon to it but the the interpolation error increased significantly what shall i do?

Comment: Do you have duplicate points? Are you sure you wrote the formula correctly? The result line is outside of the `i` for loop but you're still referencing `i`.

Comment: Identify when `x[j] - x[i]` is 0.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change the method. One possible search term is *osculatory interpolation*.